# How to wait for caching request to finish, in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I work with external API with my Laravel app and want to cache some requests. Let's say I have three methods in my App HttpController:

`1) Login and 2)getProducts 3) cacheProducts`

I want to trigger products caching while sending login requests (caching takes some time so I would want to have products cached as soon as possible). In order to do this and not to block the logging-in process, I would dispatch startCache event and handle caching products, but the request to get the products for caching takes like 20seconds.

**My question is how I handle caching that if the user wants to load the products the app would wait for products to cache and then load them from the cache instead of starting a new request to get the products** (the request is for the same API endpoint for caching and getting the products).

Or if a certain amount of time passes (caching fails or something) I would allow for a second request? It's the case of not chaining events(having one event trigger other) but of postponing certain requests until data is cached by the previous request.

Comment: not able to provide a complete answer but my thought is you can acquire a [lock](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache#atomic-locks) when you begin the caching process. Everyone who wants to access that value should try to acquire the same lock for e.g. 20 seconds and if that fails you can start the process again. If the lock is  available but the value is not cached then you can start this process.